# I updated my iOS app on the App Store and now it's only compatible with iPhone 5s+

Tags: ios, iphone

I made a few small bug fixes and released an update today, but now the Compatibility has randomly changed to iPhone 5s or later and I have no idea why. Previously it worked on any iOS 8.0+ device, and the changes I made were very small bug fixes.

After looking at the compatibility reference (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html[1] ) there are only two things that are iPhone 5s+, and that's 'metal' and 'opengles-3'. I don't know what these are and how I could have accidentally used them? In my info.plist only "armv7" is in "Required device capabilities".

EDIT: It seems that the app now only supports devices with x64 processors (iPhone 5S onward and iPad Air onward). However, in xcode it says it still supports armv7...

Comment: What is iOS 8.0+ device? You mean iPhone 6 & 6+?

Comment: Any device that supported iOS 8, so iPhone 4S onward. In other words, iOD 8 was previously the minimum build target, but today for whatever reason that's changed to iOS 8 AND iPhone 5S onward.

Answer (score 2):

So I found out you can check which architectures are included in a binary by running

```
xcrun lipo -info /App.app/app
```

Which told me only arm64 was included in this particular binary for whatever reason... I re-archived the app and it now has arm7 as well.